# Proteus ATTiny85/ATMega328P CLKOUT not sending any signal at all - Why?

Tags: avr, embedded, attiny, proteus

I set all the fuse bits correctly according to the datasheet, It seems like I just need to set the CLKOUT bits correctly, and I should get a signal of some sort. I can still send signals to the GPIO pin generally which makes sense, but I don't understand why there isn't a clock signal coming out of it.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define DDRB  (*(volatile unsigned char*)0x37)
#define PORTB (*(volatile unsigned char*)0x38)
#define CLKPR (*(volatile unsigned char*)0x46)

int main()
 { 
   // Write your code here
    DDRB = 0xFF;
    CLKPR  = (1<<7);
    CLKPR = 0;  
    
    
    void delay(volatile long time){
       while (time > 0) {
      time--;
       }
    }       
    
   while (1){
      // PORTB ^= (1 << 1) | (1 << 0); this is just to test if signals are working 
      PORTB ^= (7 << 0);
      
      delay(100000);
   }
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Consider posting a snippet of the relevant code. It's impossible to tell what you may be doing wrong.

Comment: Sure, I will do this for completeness. I didn't include this originally as I thought it's a simple problem.

Comment: @JYelton I have added code,

Answer (score 1):

Without having your exact code here are some common gotchas for this kind of configuration:

Check that the pin is in output mode, or the mode the datasheet tells you it needs to be in for CLKOUT to be used.

Many MCUs have an "Alternate Function" config setting for each pin. For example Alternate Function 0 could be GPIO, AF1 could be ADC input, AF2 CLKOUT, etc. Make sure that if your chip has this that you've set it correctly.

Whatever config registers you write, make sure you can read them back and get the expected value. This will catch any mistakes in power mode, clock selection, bus enable, etc that you might have missed in the datasheet.

Sometimes fuse options are backwards, as in "On" may be a zero. I believe Atmel does it this way, so check that yours is the right way around.

Comment: The CKOUT feature is set via fuse bits. There is no software needed to be even loaded to or running on MCU. And the big question is, does the Proteus simulator even bother to implement CKOUT feature. It's been complained before that it won't emulate all I2C status bits correctly even if same code works on a real MCU just fine. And I2C was not being emulated in open drain mode.

Comment: Thanks for both your comments. I have a feeling it's a software problem. I've tried all the suggestions. I will implement this in hardware tonight and provide an answer for future reference for others.

Comment: I have added code.

Comment: To enable CLKOut you have to program the relevant fuse bit (bit 6) to ZERO. I suspect you have programmed as ONE based on your CLKPR define in your code.

Comment: The fuse bits are set by arguments to your flash command (ie avrdude). Can you show what command you used? If you are using an IDE it will be in your output window right after you run. This tool (https://www.engbedded.com/fusecalc/) will give you the correct -U flags to use if you put in the settings you want.

Comment: I have done these, I am using proteus, so the fuse bits are set by the program, but As @Kripacharya has said, bit 6 has been set to zero.

Comment: Chances are - if all that you're doing is only on Proteus - that Proteus possibly doesn't handle this case properly. If on a real system, then ensure fuse bits ARE actually being programmed. Everything is not automatic - especially the fuse bits